# Unable to install EF6 on project in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have EF6 installed in my first project, but my second project (a class library) will not take the EF6 update. Somehow I keep ending up with EF5.

First project name: s84
Second project name: s84.Domain

Here's the log from the Package Manager:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
'EntityFramework 6.0.1' already installed.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.0.1' to s84.Domain.
'packages.config' already exists. Skipping...
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.0.1' to s84.Domain.
No packages installed.
Install-Package : The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 's84.Domain'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

When I right-click on my second project and choose Manage NuGet Packages, Entity Framework does not show up in the list. I can add Entity Framework to the second project via NuGet, but then it shows my second project has EF5 and it asks me to upgrade.

My question is this: Does my second project currently have EF6 (based on the steps I have taken) or does it not? If not, how can I get EF6 working in my second project?

Additionally, I currently have a message in the Package Manager for the second solution which says: "Some NuGet packages are missing from this solution. Click to restore from your online package sources."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Uninstalling Ef first.
Then re-install EF.
When installing from PC console make sure the Project field has the correct target project.
or add -ProjectName  to the install-package line

Comment: I tried that already. EF seems to be working with references from the first project, but I guess NuGet does not understand me having 2 projects for some reason.